# Pygoat docker is broken

Tags: docker

Hi I am wondering why can't I connect to the pygoat site while it is running on docker this is the repo link
https://github.com/JustinDPerkins/pygoat-tm

I also looked at https://github.com/adeyosemanputra/pygoat and followed the video and ran the command

> python3 manage.py runserver

It worked however it does not work when I ran build a docker image can some one help thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran

> docker run --rm -p 8000:8000 pygoat/pygoat

it did not work it tried to download the docker file from docker hub which in turn does not work
However when I ran

> docker run --rm -p 8000:8000 pygoat

It did work this is weird

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).